# Visual Studio 2015 update 3 several installation multiple errors

Tags: visual-studio-2015, failed-installation

I had installed Visual studio 2015 in April and from past one week I was trying to install the update 3. In first attempt, the installation failed with errors. After which the Visual Studio itself stopped working at all!!. On that, I had uninstalled the update 3, still VS was not working and then SQL server 2014 also stopped working. In between did workarounds:

1. clear package cache and temp files etc.
2. Tried re-installing VS2015, sql server 2014 and other missing files based on 
   the errors.

Finally, I had to completely uninstall literally everything that was even remotely linked to Visual Studio viz:

- net framework 4.5 and 4.6
- Sql sever 2014
- VS 2015
- VS 2015 update 3

So now I freshly installed framework 4.5, 4.6.2 and sql server 2015. I already had a setup file of VS2015 professional with license, so i installed it. However, it was installing with update 3. So got the below error:

Visual Studio update 3 installation error:

Besides VS is opening :-). But i also need update 3 because I need a MS chatbot template to work with. 
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: And I forgot to tell that no projects are opening in VS , giving Roslyn package error and C# compiler cannot be created error. Searched in SOF for all that.

Comment: remove VS2015 completely. now download the VS2015 ISO which includes the Update3: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Comment: This worked @magicandre1981! I did an offline installation after removing VS2015 completely. Thank you.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that you can accept it to "close" the question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `Visual Studio 2015` completely, download the Visual Studio 2015 ISO which already has the Update 3 included [from the Microsoft page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/),

[image]

mount the ISO and install the VS2015.